# Can I get the list of files for two or more directories?

Tags: development, document-library, caml-query

My current query is below and works adequately enough.

The sharepoint developer is creating a workflow that will look at files in the "Documents" folder, and if it certain flags are set, the workflow will move the file to a subdirectory (e.g. Documents/Maps).  Is there a way I can construct the code to make one query but get a list of files from both Documents and Documents/Maps?

Potentially, there could be close to 10 directories.  I would like to be able to get the list of files, and surface some of the files to the user based on the metadata.

```
    private static void ListDocuments(ClientContext clientContext)
    {
        List list = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Documents");

        CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
        camlQuery.ViewXml =
            @"<View>
            <Query/>
            <RowLimit>100</RowLimit>
          </View>";
        ListItemCollection listItems = list.GetItems(camlQuery);
        clientContext.Load(
             listItems,
             items => items
                 .Include(
                   item => item["LinkFilename"],
                     item => item["FileRef"],
                     item => item["File_x0020_Size"],
                     item => item["File_x0020_Type"],
                     item => item["Modified"]
                     ));
        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you can include several data operations in you ClientContext query. For example, you can call two or more times ClientContext.Load method, and when call once ExecuteQuery method. Even some logic on server is supported, using conditions scopes (see [ConditionalScope](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee535891.aspx)) and custom error handling scopes (see [ExceptionHandlingScope](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee534976.aspx)).

Next, you can set `Scope="Recursive"` attribute to the `View` tag, to run through all the descendent folders as well:

```
    CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
    camlQuery.ViewXml =
        @"<View Scope=\"Recursive\">
        <Query/>
        <RowLimit>100</RowLimit>
      </View>";
```

And another possibility here (if you don't need all the folders), you can use [SharePoint Document Sets](http://blogs.technet.com/b/vedant/archive/2010/04/21/using-the-document-set-feature-in-sharepoint-2010-part-1.aspx) to classify your data.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know Sharepoint, so converting your advice into code is a bit difficult. For example, how would I modify the code above to retrieve / search recursively?

Comment: Did you read my post? Set camlQuery.ViewAttributes to `"Scope=\"Recursive\""`.

Comment: I just checked camlQuery.  There doesn't seem to be a ViewAttributes property.  I suppose this is what confused me.  Is there an alternate way of doing this?  Could I set the query xml to be <View Scope='Recursive'>
            <Query/>
            <RowLimit>100</RowLimit>
          </View>"

Comment: Ok, sorry, ViewAttributes are only for server object model for some reason (SPQuery object) :( I will fix my answer.

Comment: Did the provided solution help you?